# Contours into polygons with QGIS

Tags: qgis, splitting, contour, precipitation

I'm using QGIS 3.26 to create a precipitation map for Los Angeles. I started with Final 85th Percentile, 24-hr Rainfall contours from here: https://dpw.lacounty.gov/wrd/hydrologygis/

I brought the shapefiles into QGIS:

[image: vector drawing of contours]

Merged the contours with a county boundary (using the *Merge vector layers* tool):

[image: vector image of contours plus boundary edge]

I manually snapped the contour edges to the county boundary edges whenever there was a gap or overshoot using editing tools.

Now I am trying to split the county boundary polygon with these line layers using the *Split with lines* tool, but I'm not getting complete splitting. As you can see, some lines failed to split the polygon, for example in the upper right corner of the image:

[image: vector image of map with polygon fills]

I double-checked the missing contour edges and the contours are successfully snapped to the county boundary with no gaps. What can I do to get complete splitting and thus turn the contour map into polygons? All layers are using EPSG:4326.

**UPDATE**
At Matt's suggestion, I ran *Lines to Polygons* on my manually snapped line layer. I got a few of the following errors:

*`One or more line ignored due to geometry not having a minimum of three vertices.`*

and the following map:

[image: image of map with lines and polygons]

I also tried *Polygonize*. It gave me the same results as with the *Split with lines* tool.

Comment: Try extending the troublesome lines a little way past the polygon boundary. Alternatively, does the tool *Lines to Polygons* on your manually snapped line layer give you the desired result?

Comment: @Matt Extending the lines worked! Could you please write this as an answer so others can find this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try extending the lines past the boundary of the polygon, like so:

[image]