# Dividing city into blocks (polygons) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, splitting, polygon-creation

I'm interested in dividing a city up into distinct blocks, with the end result being polygons for the blocks. I have a polygon for the city boundary and centerlines for the city streets.

Here's a simplified version of the concept, where the first two figures (boundary and streets) would be overlaid and the result on the right would be four polygons.

[image]

I prefer to use QGIS since this is a personal project and could use my own software for it.

Comment: Feature to polygon, arcgis

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS, use Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>Split with lines</kbd>:

> This algorithm splits the lines or polygons in one layer using the
> lines or polygon rings in another layer to define the breaking points.
> Intersection between geometries in both layers are considered as split
> points.
> https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgissplitwithlines

Comment: @Gdog, you might need to extend your lines a little if you get strange results. See [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/443650/128665).

Comment: @Matt good point. Extending lines automatically can be done with Menu Processing > Toolbox > Extend lines

Comment: Great.  I don't have all the shapefiles I need to start yet - planning out the process now - but I'll give it a shot. Thanks a lot.